# O que significa 'redacts password'?

Tags: banco-de-dados, segurança

Na documentação do InfluxDB, encontrei a seguinte nota:

> Note: InfluxDB redacts passwords when you enable authentication.

Fonte: https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v0.13/administration/authentication_and_authorization

Comment: Acho que isso aí tá dizendo que o tal do InfluxDB cria uma senha quando tu ativa autenticação, mas é só um palpite.

Comment: *Redact*, neste contexto, significa *censura*, *alteração* ou *remoção*.

Answer (score 1):

Recomendo usar [esse](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v0.13/administration/authentication_and_authorization#authenticate-using-the-http-api) link para que o usuário seja automaticamente levado à sessão da pergunta.

Até onde sei, redacts significa "censura" ou "esconde" no indicativo do presente, isso seria necessário se por exemplo a base de dados fosse mostrada públicamente, ou para assegurar os usuários do fato de que a pessoa com acesso à base de dados não pode saber sua senha, que poderia ser usada para fins maliciosos em um cenário em que o usuário usa a mesma senha para vários serviços.

Ainda seria mais recomendado que a base de dados usasse um sistema de "hashing" de senhas, em que a senha que é enviada pela pessoa passa por um processo em que ela é tornada em outra string de caracteres, se a string que se formou é a mesma no site, o usuário é garantido o acesso ao serviço, com esse mecanismo um administrador de um site não sabe a sua senha, mas ele precisa ter o senso ético de implementar o mesmo.

Um processo de hashing só pode funcionar de um jeito, com uma série de processos fixos, **do contrário isso é um processo de criptografia**, uma criptografia precisa ser implementada com no mínimo dois elementos - geralmente o conteúdo a ser passado e uma "chave".

O usuário [cantoni](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/3084/cantoni) apontou algo importante:
o processo de hashing deve ser irreversível de formas convencionais, do contrário também haveria a possibilidade de que uma pessoa com acesso à base de dados recuperasse a informação dos usuários mesmo que a mesma nunca tivesse sido hospedada no servidor.

Comment: Base64 não é hashing. É apenas uma maneira de codificar uma String. É um processo completamente reversível (e deve ser). Algoritmos pra hashing de senha devem ser, necessariamente, unidirecionais. Nesse contexto, existem vários tipos, como MD5, SHA256, etc.